# Trigger either event but not both in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I'm simulating a todo list where the textfield's value gets saved in the model when it loses focus or when the user presses enter.

```
//view etc.
events:{
    "blur .task": "doneEditing",
    "keypress .task": "doneEditing"
},
doneEditing: function(e){
    if(e.which && e.which != 13) return;
    e.preventDefault();
    //model saving code
}
```

The problem is that the keypress enter triggers doneEditing, and then the blur happens and triggers doneEditing again. I could use a bit of tricks to find a workaround, but I was wondering if backbone has a way of only triggering one of either event.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those two events happen in a short time interval, you can just use `underscore.js` library's (Backbone's hard dependency, so you'll have it anyway) `throttle`-method to stop too many calls in a short succession. Here is a link to the [documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle).

And an example:

```
doneEditing: _.throttle(function(e) {
  // Copy your event handling here
}, 100), // The number here defines the time threshold within which the function can be called only once
```

Hopefully that helped!

Comment: That seems a little bit hacky though. But I'll use it until a better solution comes up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `e.stopPropagation()` or just return `false` (which calls both `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` as of jQuery). DOM Event propagation is beyond Backbone's scope, and for such a simple thing there's no need for helpers.

Comment: Thanks but in my case, this doesn't work. Perhaps I misunderstood how stopPropagation works, but I don't think it's supposed to stop the triggering of the same event twice on the **same** element.